# Which library is used for photo sliding?

Tags: android

Is there something in the standard Android SDK that allows you to do image sliding like this [app](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.anubavam.puzzle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. You'll have to implement that by hand however if you find a 3rd party library that does just that, even tho I doubt there is, then please feel free to add it to my list.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4078479/418183

Answer (score 1):

Try overloading GalleryView or ViewFlipper classes.

I needed switchable banner and I overloaded the ViewFlipper, then I am detecting gestures on that view and im switching the images.

It works really fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library:
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
You can easily load images from an internet URL, drawable, or file.